# Print output to a file using Printf (Perl )

Tags: file, perl, hyperlink, printf

I have existing script and part of the script post it here below. I want to print the result to a file. The results are printed on Linux screen session
My question how do I print def to a file instead of showing on screen

```
my $def=printf '/opt/bin/run server=%s os="%s" version=%s application=%s',
    $server, $os, $version, $application;       
print $def."\n" ;
```

Comment: Read: perldoc -f print, perldoc perlopentut, perldoc perlunitut (if you will use non-ASCII symbols)

Comment: You can redirect  output into a file `./script.pl > filename.txt` -- [How do I save terminal output to a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation for `print()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf) you'll see it takes the following forms:

> ```
> printf FILEHANDLE FORMAT, LIST
> printf FILEHANDLE
> printf FORMAT, LIST
> print
> ```

You are currently using the third form in the list. If you want the output from `printf()` to go to a file, you can switch to the first form.

```
# open a filehandle for your file
open my $fh, '>', $your_file_name or die "$your_file_name: $!";

printf $fh '/opt/bin/run server=%s os="%s" version=%s application=%s',
       $server, $os, $version, $application;
```

Note that (like `print()`) there is no comma between the filehandle and the other arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can write a string to a file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'hello world';
my $fn = 'hello.txt';
open ( my $fh, '>', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
print $fh $str;
close $fh;
```